# Why is there no global IPv6 address after Debian 10 startup?

Tags: networking, debian, ipv6, debian-buster

I am trying to configure IPv6 on a VPS running Debian 10 and executing

```
ip addr add 2a02:x:x:x::1/64 dev eth0
```

works and `ip -6 addr show` produces the following output:

```
inet6 2a02:x:x:x::1/64 scope global
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::x:x:x:2358/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The next step was to configure IPv6 in `/etc/network/interfaces` where I have the following section:

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2a02:x:x:x::1
    netmask 64
    gateway fe80::1
    accept_ra 0
    autoconf 0
    privext 0
    dns-nameservers 2a02:c207::1:53 2a02:c207::2:53
```

However, after a reboot, `ip -6 addr show` produces only this output:

```
inet6 fe80::x:x:x:2358/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

What am I missing?

IPv4 configuration works fine where I assign two IPv4 addresses to `eth0`.

Comment: Please do not redact IP addresses. Provide real addresses, or substitute obviously fake from the documentation subnet. Some values must match, and we can't verify that if everything but the /16 is masked.

Comment: Check your logs.